Flutter App Stuck on SplashPage After Integrating GoRouter: Navigation Not Updating UI
I'm working on a Flutter application where I've integrated two separate apps:
App A: Contains various features but lacks authentication and chat functionality.
App B: Includes authentication (using Supabase) and chat features.
The goal is to integrate App B's authentication and chat into App A. After integrating, both apps work fine separately, but when I try to incorporate the authentication into the main app (App A), I encounter a problem.
Problem:
The app gets stuck on the SplashPage and doesn't navigate to the LoginPage or RegisterPage as expected. Interestingly, the logs indicate that the navigation is happening and that the LoginPage is being built, but the UI remains on the SplashPage.
What I've Tried:
1. Checked Route Configurations:

Ensured that all routes are correctly defined using go_router with code generation.
Ran flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs to regenerate route definitions.

2. Verified GoRouter Registration:

Confirmed that GoRouter is registered in the setup() function.
Used goRouterConfig directly in MaterialApp.router to ensure the correct router instance is used.

3. Added Logging:

Inserted logs in LoginPage, RegisterPage, and SplashPage to confirm that their build methods are called.
Logs show that LoginPage is being built.

4. Checked for Multiple MaterialApp Instances:
Ensured that there's only one MaterialApp.router at the top of the widget tree.
5. Simplified the App:

Temporarily removed the StreamBuilders in main.dart to eliminate potential issues with initial data.
Set initialData for StreamBuilders to ensure they have immediate data.

6. Reviewed Navigation Logic:

Verified that the redirect function in go_router_config.dart isn't causing issues.
Checked that the navigation in _getInitialSession() in SplashPage correctly navigates to /login when there's no session.

Key Code Snippets:
main.dart:
class Nepanikar extends StatelessWidget {
  const Nepanikar({super.key});

  GoRouter get _goRouter => goRouterConfig;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: _goRouter,
      // ... other configurations ...
    );
  }
}

go_router_config.dart:
final goRouterConfig = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: $appRoutes,
  redirect: (context, state) {
    final isLoggedIn = Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentSession != null;

    if (state.uri.path == '/') {
      return null; // Allow access to SplashPage
    }

    if (state.uri.path == '/login' || state.uri.path == '/register') {
      return null; // Allow access to LoginPage and RegisterPage
    }

    if (!isLoggedIn && state.uri.path != '/login') {
      return '/login'; // Redirect to login if not logged in
    }

    if (isLoggedIn &&
        (state.uri.path == '/login' || state.uri.path == '/register')) {
      return '/main'; // Redirect to main if already logged in
    }

    return null; // No redirection
  },
  // ... other configurations ...
);

SplashPage.dart:
class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SplashPageState createState() => SplashPageState();
}

class SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _getInitialSession();
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getInitialSession() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)); // For debugging

    final session = Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentSession;

    if (!mounted) return;

    if (session == null) {
      Future.microtask(() => context.go('/login'));
    } else {
      Future.microtask(() => context.go('/main'));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}

LoginPage.dart:
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // ... state and methods ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Sign In')),
      body: ListView(
        // ... form fields and buttons ...
      ),
    );
  }
}

Logs:
I/flutter (12789): [GoRouterConfig] INFO: Redirect called. Path: /login, logged in: false
I/flutter (12789): [GoRouterConfig] INFO: Access granted to /login
I/flutter (12789): [GoRouterConfig] INFO: Pushed route: /login
I/flutter (12789): [LoginPage] INFO: Building LoginPage

Observation:

The logs indicate that the app is navigating to /login and LoginPage is being built.
Despite this, the UI remains stuck on the SplashPage with the loading indicator.

Additional Context:
We suspect that the issue might be due to conflicts arising from integrating the two apps, possibly multiple MaterialApp instances or overlapping navigators.
The setup() function correctly registers GoRouter in the registry.
Question:
What could be causing the app to remain stuck on the SplashPage even though the logs show that the navigation to LoginPage is happening and that LoginPage is being built? How can I ensure that the UI updates to show the LoginPage? Any insights or suggestions on how to debug or fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.
What I'm Looking For:
Possible reasons why the UI isn't updating despite navigation events occurring.
Guidance on how to debug UI update issues in Flutter when navigation seems to be working.
Suggestions on whether the problem could be due to multiple Navigator instances or widget tree conflicts.
